# I Want to run the function "getData()" repeatedly inside Service

Tags: android, android-service

public class MyService extends Service {

```
int a=0;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getData();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void getData(){
    String result="";
    InputStream isr=null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.96.1/php1/noti.php");
        HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        isr=entity.getContent();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Log_tag", "Error in Http Connection" + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not connect to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String MyText = "Reminder";
    Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis());
    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"US-ASCII"),8);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Log_tag","Error converting Result"+e.toString());
    }
    try {
        String s="";
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s=s +
            "State: "+json.getString("state")+"\n";
            String MyNotificationTitle = "E-Door Security";
            String MyNotificationText = "Door Opened!!!";

            Intent MyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

```
            mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);

            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
            a=0;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        if(a!=1) {
            String MyNotificationTitle = "E-Door Security";
            String MyNotificationText = "door Closed!!!";

            Intent MyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

```
            mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);

            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
            a=1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

1. i want the "getDate()" function to be called repeatedly inside the service
2. Problem is it calls once at first installation but not repeatedly.

Comment: I see `getData()` to be called only once. Why do you expect it to be called multiple times? Are you starting service multiple times somewhere? By the way, you should not run network operation on main thread. I suggest to use IntentService that will do the job for you.

Comment: The getData() function calls the php page and notifies depending on the JSON output in the php page. Please tell how to call the getData() function Repeatedly.

Comment: You should be more clear about what you trying to achieve. Do you want `getData()` to be called endless unless something happen or what else?

Comment: i want to call the getData() endless, until i press Stop Service button. My UI is like http://techblogon.com/simple-android-service-example-code-description-start-stop-service/

Comment: will there be a interval or should getData be called again right after it completed?

Comment: just now i tried calling same function inside the function at the end, but my app stops displaying "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your service using AlarmManager:

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceClass.class);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,2000, pendingIntent);
```

Here 2000 is the time period,that means onStartCommand() is gets called for every 2sec's.

Comment: ya its working, but i have a button "Stop Service"  when i press it, it doesn't stops.

Comment: when your click on button call these two methods:       manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
stopService(serviceIntent);

Comment: ok welcome..accept this answer this may be helpful to others..!!